# Bivouac on glacier: how to be sure not to stand on a crevasse?

Tags: safety, glaciers, bivouac, crevasses

When there is no snow cover on the glacier and crevasses are visible, no need to really worry about crevasses.
But what about when there is a layer of snow on top of glacier, hiding crevasses, and you want to set up a bivouac, how do you ensure that you are not laying on a snow bridge?

I thought about first staying away of places where crevasses are likely (like explained in [this post](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/7026/12554)), and then probing the snow layer with an avalanche probe, but maybe there exists better techniques.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probing is the best and only guaranteed technique for safely locating crevasses. Knowing how crevasses form will help you identify areas where crevasses are more likely to be, but you can't be certain a crevasse is directly below you if it is not already obvious from above ground.

Comment: Well to be fussy, it's not *the* only variant, but it's the only one (I know) that is practical. You can of course employ various other guaranteed methods from plain stupid digging (while secured :P ) to snow-penetrating radar ;)

Comment: @imsodin I feel like exploratory digging with a shovel would be one of the faster ways to collapse a hidden snow bridge.